# Keep frozen object as global state

Tags: javascript, immutability, freeze, immer.js

I am playing around with immer.js. Immer.js lock obejct after giving new instance. Is it ok to use this locked object as global state?

```
windows.initialState = {a: 'a'};
const nextState = produce(initialState , draftState => {
    draftState.a = 'b',
  });

windows.initialState = nextState;
```

Comment: I can't understand: what's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can assign and keep the frozen object to the global state. As long as your global object(initial state) is not declared as const. So, Nothing wrongs with this code.